# How do I call navigator from outside the Navigator?

Tags: react-native

I have a tab bar in my application that I don't want the navigation transition to affect each time a new route is rendered. Therefore I want to place the tab bar outside the Navigator, but how do I trigger the navigation actions in that case? I cannot access the navigator object that is passed to the renderScene function from outside the Navigator.

Here is what is returned in app.js:

```
            <View>
                <Navigator
                    ref="navigator"
                    initialRoute={{name: "start"}}
                    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
                    configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
                />
                <TabBar navigator={???} style={styles.nav} />
            </View>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I think I solved this. The problem seems to be that the refs is not available at the first render of the component. I solved this by:

```
<Navigator
    ref={(r) => { this.navigatorRef = r; }}
    initialRoute={{name: "start"}}
    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
    configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
/>
{this.state ? <TabBar navigator={this.state.navigatorRef} style={styles.nav} /> : null }
```

and added the this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({navigatorRef: this.navigatorRef});
}
```

just to make the component render a second time with the TabBar.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the best way to do what you want. But to answer your question:

```
            <View>
                <Navigator
                    ref="navigator"
                    initialRoute={{name: "start"}}
                    renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}
                    configureScene={this.configureScene.bind(this)}
                />
                <TabBar getNavigator={()=>this.refs.navigator} style={styles.nav} />
            </View>
```

And then you could call `getNavigator()` from your TabBar

Comment: navigator is still undefined in TabBar, do you know why?

Comment: try to log `this.props.navigator` in TabBar component

Comment: That's what I did, got undefined there

Comment: @theva here is another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version that worked for me. It is hackish and will probably break in the future but might help if you're in a hurry ;)

```html
<View>
  <Navigation
    ref={(r) => { this.navigation = r }}
  />

  <OtherScreen
    navigation={(this.navigation || {})._navigation}
    {...this.props}
  />
</View>
```